# Hover not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, toggleclass

The hover in first image change the second image in Chrome, Safari and Opera, but in Firefox doesn't work.

HTML

```
<img id="work1" src="/images/summer.jpg" alt="" width= /><a href="#um"></a>
<img id="work2" src="/images/winter.jpg" alt="" width= /><a href="#um"></a>
```

CSS

```
 #work1{
   cursor:pointer;
 }

 #work2{
   cursor:pointer;
   &.tone{content:url(/images/click.svg);}
 }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#work1').hover(function(){
  $("#work2").toggleClass("tone");
});
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is this working on chrome. I don't think so your css syntex is wrong. You can't use `&.tone`

Comment: yes this work on chrome, safari and opera

Answer (score 0):

Use following css:

```
#work1{
   cursor:pointer;
 }

 #work2{
   cursor:pointer;
 }

#work2.tone{
    content:url(/images/click.svg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately still doesn't work in firefox.

Comment: Then may be you have disabled javascript in FF.

Comment: The content attribute should be used only in :before and :after pseudo-elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content). You can set the image as a background-image instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why do to have the `<a>` tag outside the `<img>`?

Should be placed like this:

```
<a href="#um" id="work1"><img src="/images/summer.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a href="#um" id="work2"><img src="/images/winter.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Where now As has the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Here this should work for your purpose.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#work1').hover(function () {
        console.log('hover');
        $("#work2").toggleClass("tone");
    });
})
```

```css
#work1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#work2 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#work2.tone {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/200x200') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="work1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" /></a>
<a href="#" id="work2"><img style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x300')" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i found this and work: 

     $( '#work1' ).hover(
  function() {
    $( '#work2' ).attr("src", "/images/click.svg" );
  }, function() {
    $( '#work2' ).attr("src", "/images/winter.jpg" );
  }
);